# ActiveX Control will not load [Win XP, Vista]

Tags: internet-explorer, activex

I have an application that is trying to load an ActiveX control residing in a signed cab file on the server.  When I try to run the function that loads it, I'm stopped by the IE information bar with the following message:

In IE 6 & 7 - "Your security settings do not allow websites to use ActiveX controls installed on your computer"
In IE 8 - "An add-on for this website failed to run"

When I look at the error file that gets dropped in the browser cache, it shows error 800b010b (Generic trust failure).

This is all happening in the Local Intranet zone, and I brought the IE security settings to minimal, enabling every option available.
I later added the website to the Trusted Sites and set everything to Enable there too, no change.

These tests are on multiple machines, XP and Vista.
I am logged in as an admin on all of them.

If I replace the cab file with one that I gave a dummy signature, it works.
If I replace the cab file with one that is not signed at all, it works.
If I try to run the one with a non-expired VeriSign signature, it fails.

At this point I'm not sure what to check.  If anyone has a clue, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: This suggests that the signature on the CAB file is not correct.  How did you do the signing?  If you right-click on the .CAB in Explorer and choose "Properties", is there a "Digital Signatures" tab?

If the URL is public, can you provide it?

Comment: Deleted my factually wrong response - Eric is right, of course. Thanks.